# Get the index of all matches using regex_search?

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++11

I just start to learn how to use `regex` for string handling (`C++11` new feature). Please pardon me if the following question is too silly.

Currently I apply the following code to get the index of all matches:

```
string str = "aaabxxxaab";
regex rx("ab");

vector<int> index_matches; // results saved here (should be {2, 8})

int track = 0;
smatch sm;
while (regex_search(str, sm, rx))
{
    index_matches.push_back(track+sm.position());

    string tmp = sm.suffix().str();
    track += str.length() - tmp.length(); // update base index

    str = tmp;
}
```

It works OK, but I have to update `track` (base index) manually each time to make it work correctly.

At the same time, I noticed that there are already `smatch::size()` and `smatch::position()`, which I want to combine using to achieve the goal. The following is the code I want to combine them together but cannot work (i.e. always get only `{2}`).

```
string str = "aaabxxxaab";
regex rx("ab");

vector<int> index_matches; // results saved here 
                           // (should be {2, 8}, but always get only {2})

smatch sm;
regex_search(str, sm, rx);
for (int i=0; i<sm.size(); i++)
    index_matches.push_back(sm.position(i));
```

Can someone tell me how to correctly use `smatch::size()` and `smatch::position()` to get all matched indexes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A single execution of `regex_search` gives you only one match (whose size and position you queried).

You could: change your regex to match the substring more than once (and then loop over the capture groups), or just use  `regex_iterator`

```
string str = "aaabxxxaab";
regex rx("ab");

vector<int> index_matches; // results saved here 
                           // (should be {2, 8}, but always get only {2})

for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
    it != std::sregex_iterator();
     ++it)
{
    index_matches.push_back(it->position());
}
```

online demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d6e1a44b60b7da5

Comment: Is there any reference/book you suggest for me to start to learn `regex`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) has a decent exposition, if you're asking specifically about C++'s `<regex>`