# C++ Split string based on/using (boost) regex to find the token

Tags: c++, regex, boost, split, token

I need to split a string into "string chunks" based a token found via regex. I also need to save the token itself as part of the final string chunk

Here is the regex and input string showing the complexity of what I'm after: https://regex101.com/r/bR9gW9/1

I tried to make a simple example but it fails to compile: http://cpp.sh/9qifd

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string data = "TAKE some stuff\nTAKE other stuff\nTAKE more stuff\n";
    boost::regex separate_take_chunks("TAKE");
    vector<string> take_chunks;
    //boost::sregex_token_iterator i(data.begin(), data.end(), separate_take_chunks, -1);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
    //while (i != j) cout << *i++;
}
```

Here's using std regex which works but it doesn't give me the tokens http://cpp.sh/2jlv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string data = "TAKE some stuff\nTAKE other stuff\nTAKE more stuff\n";
    std::regex separate_take_chunks("TAKE");
    std::sregex_token_iterator iter(data.begin(), data.end(), separate_take_chunks, -1);
    std::sregex_token_iterator end;
    for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
    std::cout << *iter << "---\n";
}
```

Here's not using regex, but if I could replace the find function with regex, this would work well:

```
size_t p1 = 4;
size_t p2 = 0;
while (p2 != string::npos) {
    p2 = data.find("TAKE\n", p1);
    take_chunks.push_back(data.substr(p1-4, p2));
    p1 = p2+4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run: http://cpp.sh/5ndl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string data = "NAME some name stuff\nTAKE some take stuff\nTAKE SEL some take sel stuff\n";
    regex separate_take_chunks("TAKE SEL|TAKE|NAME");

    vector<string> take_chunks;

    std::sregex_token_iterator i(data.begin(), data.end(), separate_take_chunks, { -1, 0 });
    std::sregex_token_iterator j;
    ++i; // there is no unmatched content (-1) initially, so skip it
    while (i != j) {
        take_chunks.push_back(*i++); // put matched content (0) in new index
        if (i != j) take_chunks.back() += *i++; // add unmatched content (-1)
    }
    for (const auto& c : take_chunks) cout << c << "--" <<endl;
}
```

The `{ -1, 0 }` means output unmatched content followed by matched content. If you were to put `1` or `2` that would mean output regex group 1 or 2, and `{ 3, 4 }` would output/concatenate groups 3 and 4. But we are not using groups here, so -1 and 0 are the only possible outputs.

the initial `++i` is to skip the first `-1` (unmatched content) and continue on to the `0` (matched content) because there is no unmatched content before the first part of the string `NAME`.

Essentially this creates a pattern of:

-1 (skip unmatched since it is empty)

0 + -1 (concatenate matched and unmatched)

0 + -1

..etc.

I think the way it works is that the regex function stops looking for a match once it finds one, therefore when it finds NAME it is finished capturing content for that iteration. So then `-1` is empty and `0` is "NAME". By doing an initial `++i` we skip the empty `-1`. Next iteration the `-1` has unmatched content that was captured as the regex attempted to find "TAKE". So we concatenate the `-1` unmatched content with "NAME" and put "TAKE" in a new index of the vector.

more info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator/

see also this for getting position of matches if you want to take a position/substr approach: [Get the index of all matches using regex_search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753899/get-the-index-of-all-matches-using-regex-search)

also helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/match_results/

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, you have not set the boost header paths. I am not sure if you can do that in a shell.