# Is it possible to find two strings in one string using regular expressions?

Tags: c++, regex

I have searched and found similar questions, but no definitive answers for what I am looking for. For example, in the string: "I would like the number 98 to be found and printed, thanks." I would like "98" and "thanks" to be outputted, and only those strings. I have tried:

```
    regex pattern{R"(\d{2} | thanks)"}
```

But that only outputs 98. I have also tried

```
    regex pattern{R"((\d{2})(thanks))"}
```

But this does not work either. Help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Note: I realize I can do this easily using two patterns, but I am seeing if you can do this using specifically one pattern.

Note 2: This is the rest of the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  regex pattern{R"(\d{2}|thanks)"};

  string to_search = "I would like the number 98 to be found and printed, thanks.";
  smatch matches;

  regex_search(to_search, matches, pattern);

  for (auto match : matches) {
    cout << match << endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need to match multiple matches with `regex pattern(R"(\d{2}|thanks)")`. Please show your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Don't answer in comments; thanks

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: When I have an answer, I will post.

Comment: @Chase, are you looking for [something like this](https://ideone.com/ggO4fk)?

Comment: Ok, you used `regex_search` and expected to get several matches, while it just returns a single match.

Comment: Wiktor's [solution](https://ideone.com/ggO4fk) seems to be the best bet: see [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753899/get-the-index-of-all-matches-using-regex-search) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667295/how-to-match-multiple-results-using-stdregex)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Okay, until then, just don't post it. We cannot peer review your comment. As you know, peer review is a huge part of the SO model.